# How do I use integrated Graphics dor display and nvidia card for rendering

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, graphics

I have a dell m3800 laptop with integrated Intel HD4000 and a Nvidia Quadro K1100M Graphics card.

The problem is that the Nvidia drives the display and does the rendering.

When I am rendering in blender using the Nvidia GPU my display gets very laggy.

Another problem with the Nvidia card driving the display is that the display freezes sometimes even when I am not rendering and i have to switch to another tty and back.

I would like to have the Intel card drive the display and use the Nvidia for everything else.

I have looked at numerous other threads and have not found a clear solution or answer to how to do this or if it can be done.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is called [CUDA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA) and [blender supports that](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Render/Cycles/GPU_Rendering).

**However** from the Blender CUDA FAQ:

```
Why is Blender unresponsive during rendering?

While a graphics card is rendering, it can not redraw the user
interface, which makes Blender unresponsive. We attempt to avoid this
problem by giving back control over the GPU as often as possible, but
a completely smooth interaction can't be guaranteed, especially on
heavy scenes. This is a limitation of graphics cards for which no
true solution exists, though we might be able to improve this
somewhat in the future.
```

And the solution is simple:

```
If possible, it is best to install more than one GPU, using one for
display and the other(s) for rendering.
```

(though you're probably not going to like that "solution")  **:-(**

Comment: Don't thank me!  ;-) Just click the little grey check-mark under the "0" now.  If you do not like my answer, click on the little grey down-arrow below the 0 and if you *really* like my answer, click on the little grey checkmark *and* the little up-arrow...  If you have any further questions, go to http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask

Comment: I have a laptop and it has a Intel and a nvidia gpu. On windows when I am rendering with the nvidia gpu, there is zero lag, which makes me think windows uses the Intel for driving the display. But on Ubuntu the Intel card is used for nothing.

Comment: Yep, no extra cards possible...  :( There is something called bumblebee which allows you to run certain applications purely on one card...  However, it's experimental and works quite well on some cards, but on other cards it gives an overall worse performance, so it's not something I recommend until it's become more stable.  However, if you would like to go that way, that would be [another question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask)

Comment: If you would decide to ask a specific question about bumblebee and blender, drop me a note in the comments here with the link to the new question. ;-)

Comment: would bumble make it so that the intel card would drive the display and automatically turn on the nvidia GPU when the software needs it?

Comment: http://bumblebee-project.org/ and http://www.nvidia.com/object/optimus_technology.html If still unclear: http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask